# How to prevent bower to install some dependencies

Tags: bower, bower-install

I am using bower for the first time.
I installed `bootstrap` but it pulled `jquery` with it, but I don't want it to be pulled as I load it in another way.
I tried to add ignore dependency but it installs it again:

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.8",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6"
  }, 
  "ignoredDependencies": [
    "jquery"
  ]
}
```

How to stop bower getting jquery?
I am using bower in visual studio 2015 how I can check what bower version vs use?

Comment: Any Way to do it ?